# What condition should i pass, to show the popup again

Tags: qml

I implemented a feature where after pressing the back button twice then it will show a popup and that popup consist of tow buttons i.e yes and cancel, so when you press yes it closes the app.
My issue is when i click on cancel button then popup closes, and after that when i again press the back button it closes the app instead of showing the pop-up again. So what can I do? What condition should I pass?( It's in pure qml)
here is what i have done

```
Popup  {
               visible: false
               id: popup
               background: Rectangle {
                   width: 300
                   height: 200     
                   }
                   Row{
                       topPadding: 10
                           Button {
                           text: qsTr("YES")                    
                           onClicked:
                           {
                               Qt.quit();
                           }
                           Button{
                           text: qsTr("cancel")
                           height:40
                           width:100
                           onClicked:
                           {
                               popup.close();
                           }
                        }

                   }
               }

               modal: true
               focus: true
           }
Keys.onBackPressed: {
          timer.pressBack()
    }
    Timer{
        id: timer

        property bool  backPressed: false
        repeat: false
        interval: 300//ms
        onTriggered: backPressed = false
        function pressBack(){
            if(backPressed){
                timer.stop()
                backPressed = false
                popup.open();
            }
            else{
                backPressed = true
                timer.start()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this happens, because you're calling the close method directly and qml instead of closing the popup calls the close function of the main window instead (you didn't post the code for the leaveApp function so I can't tell for sure if this is what happens in your case). You also definitely don't need the call to leaveApp() after popup.open()

Here is the sample I used to test this. It should work as expected:

```
Keys.onReleased: {
    if (event.key == Qt.Key_Back) {
        event.accepted = true
        timer.pressBack()
    }
}
Timer{
    id: timer 

    property bool  backPressed: false
    repeat: false
    interval: 300//ms
    onTriggered: backPressed = false
    function pressBack(){
        if(backPressed){
            timer.stop()
            backPressed = false
            popup.open();
            //leaveApp()
        }
        else{
            backPressed = true
            timer.start()
        }
    }
}

Popup {
    id: popup
    x: 100
    y: 100
    width: 200
    height: 300
    modal: true
    focus: true
    Row {
        Button {
            text: "ok"
            onClicked: {
                console.log("leave app")
                mainWindow.close()
            }
        }
        Button {
            text: "cancel"
            onClicked: {
                console.log("close popup")
                popup.close() //you have to call close method of popup explicitly (only close() will cause the issue)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No what i am asking is after clicking on cancel button, when i again click on back button on my phone then the popup should again open. but it's not working in that way

Comment: I just tested it and it works as expected in the example I sent you! can you post a complete example of your code so that  I can reproduce the problem?

Comment: yes your code is working fine. I also did the same. But i am saying when you click on cancel button then the popup get closed and when you again click on back button on your device then it should again show the popup.

Comment: you say device... do you mean pc? or are you developing for mobile? maybe you should mention it in your question!

Comment: It's for mobile application

Comment: I don't develop for mobile so I can't really test it, but my guess is you have to accept the key event to prevent it from triggering the default action of exiting the app. See my modified example

Comment: take a look at this thread: https://forum.qt.io/topic/28801/android-backbutton/14  it depicts more or less the same issue (see last answer with the onClosing event)